# Left fill function like PHP str_pad in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Is there a way to replicate PHP str_pad in Angular 5? Not in the template file or via pipe, but from the TS file.

Example PHP

```php
<?php
$str = "Hello World";
echo str_pad($str,20,".",STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```

I created a function quickly

```ts
my_pad(stringval,length) {
    // Force to fill with zero
    const fill = '0000000000000000000000000';
    return String(fill + stringval).slice(-length);
}
this.someservice.newvalue = this.my_pad('234',6);
// expected this.my_pad('234',6) to return 000234
```

Is there a smarter way or better way to create this type of function? Or if there is a generic version in Angular (did not find any so far)?

Comment: What do you mean *"in Angular 5"*? It's certainly not a pipe (see https://angular.io/api?query=pipe). After that it's just TS/JS.

Comment: Simply use padSart : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: Come on jonrsharpe - You have angularJS (v1)
Angular 2
Angular 4 and Angular 5, soon angular 6 coming up.

The codes are more of less similar but there are some differences and this question is not meant to cover those.

You can do manipulation in the template directly with visual display manips, or via pipes which is another visual manip.

I need to make the manipulation from the TS file, so basically using Javascript or typescript.

Answer (score -2):

Got the answer from David,
sweet and short and does the job.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Examples

```
'abc'.padStart(10);         // "       abc"
'abc'.padStart(10, "foo");  // "foofoofabc"
'abc'.padStart(6,"123465"); // "123abc"
'abc'.padStart(8, "0");     // "00000abc"
'abc'.padStart(1);          // "abc"
```